# How can i Identify different pickerViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, identifier

My pickerViews all come from one `pickerViewCell`. I generate 5 of them and I need to know how i can identify all these 5 at the same time and get the `indexPath.row` from all of them.

Comment: You can give each picker a unique tag and then use those tags in your conditions

Comment: you can apply tag to your pickerView like pickerView1.tag = 1, then assing tag=2 for next and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the `tag` property of each pickerView which is an integer that you can use to identify each

Answer (score 1):

set pickerview tag as indexpath.row and identify pickerview.

Answer (score 0):

Initially set `tag`value to each picker view.
When you scroll cells of `pickerview`, `delegate` method of picker view shown below called all the time. By using tag value find which picker view is selected.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
 if(pickerView.tag == 0) {

 } else if(pickerView.tag == 1) {

 } else if(pickerView.tag == 2) {

 }
}
```